# I couldn't install discord.py

Tags: python, path, pycharm, discord.py, pynacl

So I was running this command

```
py -3 -m pip install -U discord.py[voice]
```

in PyCharm (using latest version) but it couldn't let me install it. It gave me this exception:

> ERROR: The 'make' utility is missing from PATH
>
> ERROR: Failed building wheel for PyNaCl Failed to build PyNaCl
>
> ERROR: Could not build wheels for PyNaCl which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly

Comment: What version of Python are you running?

Comment: Try to install the package from the command line (`[sudo] pip install discord.py`)

Comment: I am running the latest version of Python.

Answer (score 0):

if you are in linux run,

```
sudo pip3 install discord.py[voice] -U
```

or if you are on windows run,

```
pip install discord.py[voice] -U
```